# Angular 4: watch controller variable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let's say i have an old code, which i don't wanna to change. I have three server-calls, to get some data, and i have to run some code after all this three methods succeed. I've added variable, and i wanna listen on it's changes (ngOnChanges won't work).

Here is code:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadedReq = 0; // When this var is 3 - then all requests passed, and i have to run some custom code, how to watch on this variable?

  this.getCars();
  this.getModels();
  this.getTypes();
}

getCars() {
  return this.myService.getCars(this.clientId)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.loadedReq++;
    });
}

getModels() {
  return this.myService.getModels(this.clientId)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.loadedReq++;
    });
}

getTypes() {
  return this.myService.getTypes(this.clientId)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.loadedReq++;
    });
}

someMethodWhenAllLoaded(){}
```

is it possible somehow? without changing methods (i mean implement huge RxJs logic on responses etc)?

if not, then how to create a workaround here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways of doing it, but one thing you could do, is use the `.zip()` operator from RxJs to wait until they're all finished.

We're saving a reference to it as well, so that we can unsubscribe onDestroy as well.

```
zippedSubs$: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zippedSubs$ = Observable.zip([
      this.getCars(),
      this.getModels(),
      this.getTypes()
    ]).subscribe(result => {
      console.log('All 3 are done!');
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.zippedSubs$.unsubscribe();
  }

  getCars() {
    return this.myService.getCars(this.clientId);
  }

  getModels() {
    return this.myService.getModels(this.clientId);
  }

  getTypes() {
    return this.myService.getTypes(this.clientId);
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to subscribe on each request separately in methods?

Comment: I used forkJoin